# Pass data from view in app1 to a view in app2 in django

Tags: python, django

I have some details on a customer and I would like to get those details from a view function in app1 to a view in another app, app2. How can this be done?

Comment: Let me rephrase it: the details are of a customer and his shopping cart, and the details are being used in app1 to display them. In app2, I would like the info to be displayed so that he can confirm the details before the payment workflow begins.

Comment: Session is your friend so this kind of stuff :)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: Yes, so it seems, ***thanks!***

Comment: Some unsolicited advice: Rather than storing the cart in the session, it may be less messy to store the pk of the `Cart` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `redirect` func with passing additional args with it.

Comment: But how can render the view on a template in app1, and when he clicks on "**confirm**", the page should redirect to the confirmation page?

Comment: For example, you can ask backend for data (via AJAX) and render what you want on frontend part only.
Sorry, maybe I don't understand right what you want.